# Remove small areas from SHP shapefile in Qgis? (Python R etc)

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a very complex file showing remnant vegetation data. I wish to remove very small areas (preferably with a threshold that I can set) and generate a file that shows only larger blocks of vegetation.

Is this possible with Qgis (2.14.3 Essen) on Ubuntu. I could also do this in Python or R if someone can give me a clear script (I can just about hack R).

Comment: Do you require a dissolve type operation (i.e. merge smaller polygons with larger polygons) or a simple select (e.g. remove all polygons < X area)?

Comment: @Aaron I am simply trying to remove all polygons < X area.  The background is that I have a fantastic shp file describing remnant vegetation but want to remove the very fragmented areas to leave the most significant patches of original vegetation.

Answer (score 2):

ArMoraer's answer is good, but if you prefer a non-destructive solution, you can use a virtual layer. So you don’t delete any features and you can change the threshold at any time.

Add a new virtual layer (Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Virtual Layer) with a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM your_layer WHERE area(geometry) > 800
```

Change "your_layer" with your original layer name and add "800" as your threshold value (square meters).

Your original file will not be modified.

Comment: @ArMoraer, I have tried this on both my laptop and my Xeon workstation and in both cases Qgis just crashes (and closes completely).  When I look at the metadata for this layer, it says: "The number of features in this layer 103132" - this is in an area 400kkm x 180km (250miles x 100miles).

Comment: I tried your suggestion with   **'SELECT * FROM ClippedVeg _WG84_ClippedToCoast WHERE area(geometry) > 800'**   and all I got was a response  **'Layer is not valid: The layer ?query=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20ClippedVeg%20_WG84_ClippedToCoast%20WHERE%20area(geometry)%20%3E%20800 is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map'**   Any idea why that would be?

Comment: What is the format of your file ? The projection (seems WGS84) ? You should use a metric projection for area calculation. Try to re-project your layer in a metric system (Layer -> save as...).

Comment: You are correct it is in WGS 84 (EPSG:4326). I am working on an area in SW Australia. Can you or anyone suggest a suitable CRM as Qgis is offering me dozens and I am uncertain how to move forward with that!

Comment: Pierma I changed the CRM from:  **Selected CRS (EPSG:4326, WGS 84) +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs** to **Selected CRS (EPSG:4462, WGS 84 / Australian Centre for Remote Sensing Lambert)
+proj=lcc +lat_1=-18 +lat_2=-36 +lat_0=-27 +lon_0=132 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs** @ArMoraer ArMoraer I have then used your suggestion and this has worked.

Comment: I have come to this kind of question everytime I need to dissolve anything. I try a lot of options. They either take forever and crash or do not work. Geopandas is great, but documentation is not helpful. Isn't there a python library/function to do that? Choose the outer envelope, or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the "Select by expression" tool in the attribute table, with the following formula: `$area < 1E6` (you can of course change the threshold). This will select all features whose area is less than 1E6 map units.

Then, simply delete the selection with the trash icon (be sure your layer is in edit mode).

Note that this will change the file you're working on, and not generate a new "cleaned" file. So make a copy of the original file if needed.

[image]